# How do i play on a minecraft server with my friends without playing on an internet server or a LAN server

Tags: minecraft-java-edition-server

I want to play on a minecraft server with my friends without playing on an internet server and i can't get them to play on LAN server because they're not on the same network is there a way to do this? If not thanks for answering anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No there isn't. You need a server of some kind(LAN or regular) to be able to play with others.

You should be able to host a server on your own computer and open your router ports so your friends can still join you.